# Reading a .txt file in java in eclipse

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file from my computer but it says 
java.io.FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the file specified)

```
System.out.println("READING FILE"); 


    File file = new File("Testing.txt"); //Reading file from E
    FileInputStream in = null;
    BufferedInputStream buff = null;
    DataInputStream data= null;

    String Line=""; // declare a string 
    try
    {

        in = new FileInputStream(file); // pick up the file

        buff = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        data = new DataInputStream(buff);

        while (data.available() != 0) 
        { // Read the file line by line till it reaches the end of file

            Line=Line+data; // concatenate line into string

            System.out.println(data.readLine()); // print line by line 
        }

    } catch (IOException e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is saying correct. Do you have that file?

Comment: Are you sure you have the file in your CLASSPATH directory?

Comment: Reading file from E makes me think you are reading from E:\ is this the case?

Comment: if you are on windows, click on the file in eclipse so it's highlighted. Then press ALT+Enter to open the properties window for that file. Copy the file location and paste it in the File('HERE'). But replace `\\` by `/`

Comment: If so you should try specifying the whole path E:\\folder\\anjli.txt

Comment: ok that problem has been solved.... Now its giving this error
READING FILE
Exception in thread "main" Hello World I am here 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -29

Comment: What you're doing with a `DataInputStream` and a `BufferedInputStream` makes very little sense. Take a look at [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give full path instead of relative path

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File("E:\\Testing.txt");
```

If you trying to access E this is one of the ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

if you use windows try:

```
File file = new File("e:/Testing.txt");
```

(that means: use slash / instead of backslash \ )

Comment: Please provide more explanation than a code snippet. It may be obvious for us, but help others letting them know why this code answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

- Specify the *complete* path to the file, or...
- Set the app's default run directory in the project's run settings, or...
- Put the file on the classpath and read it as a resource

Answer (score 0):

Where is the path of Testing.txt ???

```
File file = new File("Testing.txt"); //Reading file from E
```

Here java You are reading from out of src path
if the file is in src you should modify the path

```
File file = new File("src/Testing.txt"); //Reading file from E
```

And another solution is enter the full path of file

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the complete path of the file would work.

Comment: Ok that problem has been solved. Now I am able to access the file but I am getting this error.
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -29

Comment: Can you post the code and line where it crashes, so I can help you?

Comment: The code is posted above. Sorry I could not post the code here again as it exceeds the word limit.
After the above code I am calling the  function 
Array=createFrequencyTable(Line);

Comment: Here is the function definition
public static int[]  createFrequencyTable(String Line) 
{int[] Arraycount=new int[26]; 
int length=Line.length(); // Tell the length of string which contains file content
for(int i=0;i<length;i++) 
{
char alphabet=Line.charAt(i);  
if(Character.isLetter(alphabet)) 
{
Arraycount[alphabet-'a']++; // Find out the index of alphabet and increment the index of that array by 1
} }
return Arraycount; // return array 
 }

Comment: The purpose of my code is to generate the frequency table of alphabets in a file ....

Comment: EXCEPTION:

READING FILE
Hello World I am here 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -29
 at labtask2.Frequency.createFrequencyTable(Frequency.java:82)
 at labtask2.Frequency.main(Frequency.java:54)